# OpenCV native integration in Android NDK with Gradle

Tags: c++, opencv, gradle, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm trying to use some code in C++ that uses the openCV library in an android project.
I'm using Android studio 2.1 and Gradle version 2.1.0 (experimental 0.7.0).
The problem is that the compiler can't find the opencv libraries. For example in this code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

extern "C" {

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
 Java_com_teaminfernale_gazetracker_MainActivity_filterImage(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance,
                                                        jlong matAddr) {

    cv::Mat& src_img  = *(cv::Mat*)matAddr;
    cv::cvtColor( src_img, src_img, CV_BGR2GRAY );
}
```

this is the error:

```
Error:(12) undefined reference to `cv::cvtColor(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, int)'
Error:error: ld returned 1 exit status
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:linkMain-jniArm64-v8aDebugAllSharedLibrary'.
A build operation failed.
Linker failed while linking libmain-jni.so.
```

Here my gradle files:

built.gradle in app folder:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
model {
android {
    compileSdkVersion = 23
    buildToolsVersion = "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig.with {
        applicationId = "com.teaminfernale.gazetracker"
        minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 19
        targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-android.txt'))
        }
    }

    ndk {
        moduleName = "main-jni"
        cppFlags.add("-std=c++11")
        cppFlags.add("-fexceptions")
        cppFlags.add("-I${file("src/main/jni/include")}".toString())
        ldLibs.add("android")
        ldLibs.add("EGL")
        ldLibs.add("GLESv2")
        ldLibs.add("dl")
        ldLibs.add("log")
        ldLibs.add("z")
        stl = "gnustl_shared"
    }


}

android.productFlavors {

    create("arm") {
        ndk.with {
            abiFilters.add("armeabi")
            File curDir = file('./')
            curDir = file(curDir.absolutePath)
            String libsDir = curDir.absolutePath+"\\src\\main\\jniLibs\\armeabi\\"

            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_core.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libIlmImf.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "liblibjasper.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "liblibjpeg.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "liblibpng.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "liblibtiff.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "liblibwebp.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libtbb.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_calib3d.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_features2d.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_flann.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_hal.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_highgui.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_imgcodecs.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_imgproc.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_ml.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_objdetect.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_photo.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_shape.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_stitching.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_superres.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_ts.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_video.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_videoio.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_videostab.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_java3.so")

        }
    }
    create("arm7") {
        ndk.with {
            abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
            File curDir = file('./')
            curDir = file(curDir.absolutePath)
            String libsDir = curDir.absolutePath+"\\src\\main\\jniLibs\\armeabi-v7a\\"

            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_core.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libIlmImf.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "liblibjasper.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "liblibjpeg.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "liblibpng.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "liblibtiff.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "liblibwebp.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libtbb.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_calib3d.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_features2d.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_flann.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_hal.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_highgui.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_imgcodecs.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_imgproc.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_ml.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_objdetect.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_photo.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_shape.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_stitching.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_superres.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_ts.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_video.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_videoio.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_videostab.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_java3.so")

        }
    }
    create("arm8") {
        ndk.with {
            abiFilters.add("arm64-v8a")
            File curDir = file('./')
            curDir = file(curDir.absolutePath)
            String libsDir = curDir.absolutePath+"\\src\\main\\jniLibs\\arm64-v8a\\"

            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_core.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libIlmImf.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "liblibjasper.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "liblibjpeg.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "liblibpng.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "liblibtiff.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "liblibwebp.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libtbb.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_calib3d.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_features2d.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_flann.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_hal.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_highgui.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_imgcodecs.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_imgproc.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_ml.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_objdetect.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_photo.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_shape.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_stitching.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_superres.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_ts.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_video.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_videoio.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_videostab.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_java3.so")

        }
    }

    create("x86") {
        ndk.with {
            abiFilters.add("x86")
            File curDir = file('./')
            curDir = file(curDir.absolutePath)
            String libsDir = curDir.absolutePath+"\\src\\main\\jniLibs\\x86\\"

            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_core.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libIlmImf.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "liblibjasper.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "liblibjpeg.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "liblibpng.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "liblibtiff.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "liblibwebp.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libtbb.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_calib3d.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_features2d.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_flann.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_hal.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_highgui.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_imgcodecs.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_imgproc.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_ml.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_objdetect.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_photo.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_shape.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_stitching.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_superres.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_ts.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_video.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_videoio.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_videostab.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_java3.so")

        }
    }
    create("x86-64") {
        ndk.with {
            abiFilters.add("x86_64")
            File curDir = file('./')
            curDir = file(curDir.absolutePath)
            String libsDir = curDir.absolutePath+"\\src\\main\\jniLibs\\x86_64\\"

            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_core.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libIlmImf.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "liblibjasper.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "liblibjpeg.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "liblibpng.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "liblibtiff.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "liblibwebp.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libtbb.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_calib3d.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_features2d.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_flann.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_hal.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_highgui.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_imgcodecs.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_imgproc.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_ml.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_objdetect.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_photo.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_shape.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_stitching.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_superres.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_ts.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_video.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_videoio.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_videostab.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_java3.so")

        }
    }

    create("mips") {
        ndk.with {
            abiFilters.add("mips")
            File curDir = file('./')
            curDir = file(curDir.absolutePath)
            String libsDir = curDir.absolutePath+"\\src\\main\\jniLibs\\mips\\"

            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_core.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libIlmImf.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "liblibjasper.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "liblibjpeg.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "liblibpng.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "liblibtiff.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "liblibwebp.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libtbb.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_calib3d.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_features2d.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_flann.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_hal.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_highgui.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_imgcodecs.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_imgproc.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_ml.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_objdetect.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_photo.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_shape.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_stitching.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_superres.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_ts.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_video.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_videoio.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_videostab.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_java3.so")

        }
    }
    create("mips-64") {
        ndk.with {
            abiFilters.add("mips64")
            File curDir = file('./')
            curDir = file(curDir.absolutePath)
            String libsDir = curDir.absolutePath+"\\src\\main\\jniLibs\\mips64\\"

            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_core.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libIlmImf.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "liblibjasper.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "liblibjpeg.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "liblibpng.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "liblibtiff.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "liblibwebp.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libtbb.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_calib3d.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_features2d.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_flann.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_hal.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_highgui.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_imgcodecs.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_imgproc.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_ml.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_objdetect.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_photo.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_shape.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_stitching.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_superres.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_ts.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_video.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_videoio.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_videostab.a")
            ldFlags.add(libsDir + "libopencv_java3.so")

        }
    }
    create("all")
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile project(':opencv')
}
```

built.gradle in opencv folder:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
}
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 2480
    versionName "2.4.8"
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/jniLibs'
    }
}
}
```

built.gradle in the main project folder:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.0'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

settings.gradle:

```
include ':app'
include ':opencv'
```

Here the complete project if can be clearer: https://github.com/eug93/GazeTracker

Sorry for my incompetence, but I wasn't able to find any feasible solution. Thank you

Comment: to isolate the problem, try to build without flavors, and list the OpenCv libraries in the main **ndk** block.

Comment: Do you have success to compile library?. I need the same and I'm desperated since few weeks with that problem. Thanks!

Comment: yes, if you go see the project linked there is the library inside, both used in java and native c (with also other things). You should check

Answer (score -1):

you need to add android.mk file in jni folder

and following line in build.gradle

sourceSets.main {

```
    jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
    jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/jniLibs'
}

buildTypes {
..
    }
```